# How to get mysql data from table into php date()?

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

Title was wierd, yes. (Im norwegian)

Okay, I'm making a counter/timer to my new project and what it do is that when a user makes a action he/she must wait 100 sec before doing it again. But, how to get the timestamp (saved in mysql db) into the PHP code again and checking how long time since last time user checked to try again.

Some of my code (From the script):

```
// Waiting for time to go?
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `crimes` WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION["id"]."'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

if($num == 1){ //Waiting
    $time_now = date("H:i:s", strtotime("+100 seconds")); // This is where Im stuck, how to get that timestamp from mysql with 100 secs added?
    $time_to_check = date("H:i:s", $row["time"]); // The time the action was done.

    // This is where the code is going to check how long time since user visited.



} else {        

}
```

So what Im asking for is that I need that one var that contains the data from mysql with 100 secs added, how? :)

This works:

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) AS time FROM `crimes` WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION["id"]."'");
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
$seconds_ago = time() - $row2['time'];
$time_now = date("H:i:s", $seconds_ago + 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert dates to UNIX timestamps in MySQL:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) AS time FROM `crimes` ...
```

Then inside PHP:

```
$seconds_ago = time() - $row['time'];
```

Comment: Works, with $seconds_ago = time() - $row2['time']; $time_now = date("H:i:s", $seconds_ago + 100);.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = date("h:i:s", time() + 100);
```

Comment: Okay, but where to insert the $row["time"] from MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
$time_now = strtotime("now"); 
$time_to_check = strtotime($row["time"]) + 100;
```